# C# class inheritance and a simple example

Tags: c#, class

```
public class A {
    public static int a = 12;
    public virtual int g() { a--; return h(); }
    public virtual int h() { a--; return i(); }
    public int i() { return --a; }
}
class B : A {
    public int b = 12;
    public override int h() { b++;  return (a--) + (b++); }
    public new int i() { return this.g(); }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("A: {0} {1} {2}", new A().g(), new A().h(), new A().i());
        Console.WriteLine("B: {0} {1} {2}", new B().g(), new B().h(), new B().i());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I found myself the example and I'm stuck. I know it's gonna print:

```
A: 9 7 6
```

but I don't know why does it print:

```
B: 18 17 15
```

At the `A` lane it `g()` takes 12 and makes it 11, then pushes it to `h()` - then it's 10, `i()` makes it 9 even before it goes anywhere else. So it's `A`: 9 for sure. Then it's the same things again, so it's 9 7 and 6.
However on the `B`: it takes the existing a (which is now 6) and `g()` makes it 5. Then the `b` gets incremented to 13, then 5+13=18. It changes `a = 5` to `a = 4` afterwards and `b = 14`. That I understand. But why is it 17 again in the next one? Shouldn't it be 18?

Comment: Debug the program.  Go through it line by line seeing how each affects the given variables.  That should make most of the operations clear.

Comment: Please never write real code like this. This is OO spaghetti.

Comment: and the a b g h etc for fields and method names is not really helping...

Comment: @JudahHimango Well, my guess is it's some sort of academic exercise, and in that regard it is a good way of demonstrating certain principles.

Comment: Break the question down into the parts you understand and the parts you don't. Once you're there, you can research only the parts you don't understand, and if you don't find an answer, then try posting just that part. As it is, with all of the single-variable exercise nonsense, solving this question serves no purpose.

Comment: @Servy yeah, sorry. It's from a book I bought some time ago. Written by a nameless teacher.

Comment: no wonder he didn't want to put his name on the book ;-)

Comment: Your codes quite confusing and it's bad practice, you should look into a few coding standards therefore it'll help you and other developers understand more of what you're writing. In this case, I think the best thing for you to do is debug your program, add watches, check that the values coming out are what expected and your code is responding in the way you expect.

Comment: +1 Fun puzzle, although, I would hate to work on a program using this king of logic.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, I realized it was a homework problem or academic exercise, hence, "never write *real* code like this."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major difference is in the case of `class A` the `member a` is `static`, which means every instance of the `class A` share the same value whereas `class B` uses an instance variable `b` which is reseted to the default value ( 12 ) for each new instance.

Comment: Thank you sir. Such a mistake, it sure wasn't static there.

Answer (score 1):

calling to `B().g()` is creating a new `b` variable, setting its value to `12`, since you are creating a new `B` object.

Inside `h()`, `b++` is setting the value to 13, and 
`return (a--) + (b++)` is returning 17, since the `a` and `b` values are 4 and 13.

Comment: It's not *setting* `b` to 12, *it's creating an entirely new `b` variable*; the old one still exists and has an old value.  That's a very important distinction.

Answer (score 0):

First let's start reading the source step by step. Let's see the class A first.

- It has a static integer variable called `a` holding the value `12`
- There are three functions `g(), h()` and `i()`
- The function `g()` reduces `a` by one and calls `h()` Now the value of `a` is 11.
- The function `h()` reduces `a` by one and calls `i()` Now the value of `a` is 10.
- The function `i()` reduces `a` by one and returns `a` Now the value of `a` which is returned is 9.

Now let's dissect the class B.

- It extends from the class A.
- It has a `public (non static)` integer variable called `b` holding the value 12.

Ok you've found a difference one is static and the other is not. This means that all `A` objects continue from the deducted value and all `B` objects use the resetted value once per object creation. That's the error you have had.